# Index values of specific rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, shift

I am trying to find out Index of such rows before "None" occurs.

```
pId=["a","b","c","None","d","e","None"]
df = pd.DataFrame(pId,columns=['pId'])

              pId
0               a
1               b
2               c
3            None
4               d
5               e
6            None

df.index[df.pId.eq('None') & df.pId.ne(df.pId.shift(-1))]
```

I am expecting the output of the above code should be

```
Index([2,5])
```

It gives me

```
Index([3,6])
```

Please correct me

Comment: looks like you could just decrement the values in your answer. maybe it's returning index of 'none' or maybe its not based on a 0 origin

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get you. Yes, its returning the index of 'None' rather than index of preceding row

Comment: I mean if it's returning a value consistently one higher than you want you can simply decrease the values by one. otherwise if you want to fix the bug maybe it is caused by your code returning the index of none when you expected the index of the value before none? well the answer just posted by Prune explains what I meant by the origin (starting index) not being 0

Comment: What happens when "None" is the first element or you have two consecutive  "None's"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure for the specific example you showed. Anyway, you could do it in a more simple way:

```
indexes = [i-1 for i,x in enumerate(pId) if x == 'None']
```

Comment: `[i for i, x in enumerate(pId, -1) if x == 'None']` would do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're returning the index of the "None".  You *compare* it against the previous item, but you're still reporting the index of the "None".  Note that your accepted answer doesn't make this check.

In short, you still need to plaster a "-1" onto the result of your checking.

Comment: That still gives ([3,6]) even if I use shift -2

Answer (score 0):

Just `-1` from `df[df["pId"] == "None"].index`:

```
import pandas as pd

pId=["a","b","c","None","d","e","None"]
df = pd.DataFrame(pId,columns=['pId'])

print(df[df["pId"] == "None"].index - 1)
```

Which gives you:

```
Int64Index([2, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Or if you just want a list of values:

```
(df[df["pId"] == "None"].index - 1).tolist()
```

You should be aware that for a list like:

```
pId=["None","None","b","c","None","d","e","None"]
```

You get a df like:

```
    pId
0  None
1  None
2     b
3     c
4  None
5     d
6     e
7  None
```

And output like:

```
[-1, 0, 3, 6]
```

Which does not make a great deal of sense.